# Java DateFormat for UTC

Tags: java, simpledateformat, timezone-offset

I have a DateFormat like

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

I have a date like this:

```
2017-02-23T11:00:04.072625
```

This "date" is a UTC date (Z is null). This parses fine. However, it seems to be interpreted as the timezone of the machine. So, my machine is EST, this ends up as

```
2017-02-23T11:00:04.072625-0500
```

Which is wrong.  I can explicitly set the timezone with like

```
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

But if the time came in a different zone in the future, that would not be right either.

If I add a "Z" or "z" to the SimpleDateFormat string, this fails to parse.

Any ideas on how to handle this correctly?

Comment: Are you using Java 8?

Comment: If you set the time zone it will take the value , otherwise it will take your machine time zone by default. You have both options, what are you looking for?

Comment: Markus, yes Java 8

Comment: Yohannes, The point is that the date string does infer a timezone, but java thinks it doesnt.

Comment: *But if the time came in a different zone in the future, that would not be right either*: you would then change the parsing code to use this new timezone. There is no way to deduce a timezone from such a format, so you won't be able to find any way to automagically adapt to a different timezone.

Comment: This string format is defined by the [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. These standard formats are used by default in the java.time classes. Parsing such strings has been covered *many* times already on Stack Overflow. Please search thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 1):

First, since you are using Java 8, start by discarding the old classes `Date`, `DateFormat`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `TimeZone`. They will more likely than not give you trouble you don’t want. Instead use the classes in `java.time` introduces in Java 8. Here you go:

```
    String yourDateTime = "2017-02-23T11:00:04.072625";

    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(yourDateTime);
    Instant i = ldt.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant();
```

`Instant` is the new class that best corresponds to the old `Date`. In this case you get

```
2017-02-23T11:00:04.072625Z
```

(`Z` means UTC)

If in the future you get the date in a different time zone, you may do something like

```
    ZoneId zi = ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris");
    Instant i = ldt.atZone(zi).toInstant();
```

In this case you get instead

```
2017-02-23T10:00:04.072625Z
```

Should you for some reason require an oldfashioned `Date` instance, for example for use with old code, it’s easy:

```
    Date oldfashionedDate = Date.from(i);
```

Comment: Might be simpler to just append the `Z` to the input string and parse as `Instant` directly, skipping the `LocalDateTime` step. `Instant.parse( "2017-02-23T11:00:04.072625" + "Z" )`  I'm not saying it is better, just an option.